# Test pagereference with selection of multiple Ids

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, visual-workflow, pagereference

I have a visualforce page where I select multiple ids. Based on my selection I start a flow. I dont know how to simulate the selection in my testclass.

Visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c" recordSetVar="Candidate" extensions="Ya_ListToString">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="mailing" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="cand">
                <apex:column value="{!cand.name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Id"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:commandButton value="Sendemail" action="{!returnIds}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex

```
public class Ya_ListToString{
    public string selectedIDs;
    public string returnstringIDs {get; set;}   
    public Flow.Interview.Persoon_toevoegen_aan_mailing_in_Bulk myFlow {get; set;}
    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
    public Ya_ListToString(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
    {
        setCon = controller;
    }
    public pageReference returnIds() {
        // do something with the selected records
        for ( cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c candidate : (cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c[])setCon.getSelected())
        {
            String CandId = candidate.id;    
            selectedIDs += (CandId.substring(0,CandId.length()-3));
        }
        returnstringIDs = selectedIDs.replace('null','');
        system.debug('returnstringIDs: '+returnstringIDs);
        PageReference retURL = new PageReference('/apex/startflow');
        retURL.getParameters().put('returnstringIDs', returnstringIDs);
        retURL.setRedirect(true);
        return retURL;
    }
}
```

Unittest

```
@istest
public class Ya_ListToStringTest {
    static testmethod void listToStringTest(){ 
        //Testdata
        cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c cand = new cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c();
        cand.cxsrec__First_name__c = 'CandFirst';
        cand.cxsrec__Last_name__c = 'CandLast';
        insert cand;
        string candId = cand.Id;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.Ya_MultiselectIds;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('returnIds',candId.substring(0,candId.length()-3));

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(cand);
        System.assertNotEquals(null, string.valueOf(pageRef));        
    }  
}
```

Update

```
@istest
public class Ya_ListToStringTest {
    static testmethod void listToStringTest(){ 
        //Testdata
        cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c cand = new cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c();
        cand.cxsrec__First_name__c = 'CandFirst';
        cand.cxsrec__Last_name__c = 'CandLast';
        insert cand;
        string candId = cand.Id;

        List<cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c> candList = new List<cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c>();
        candList.add(cand);
        Update CandList;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.Ya_MultiselectIds;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('returnIds',candId.substring(0,candId.length()-3));

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(candList);
        sc.setSelected(candList);        

        System.assertNotEquals(null, string.valueOf(pageRef));        
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the setSelected method after you instantiate the controller

`List<Object> objects =  TestHelper.getObjects(50);`

```
    ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(objects);
    stdController.setSelected(objects);
```

Comment: I added you suggestion but get: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setSelected(cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c) from the type ApexPages.StandardController.ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(cand);
  sc.setSelected(cand);

Comment: You need to pass a list of records to both the controller and the setSelected method. is "cand" a list of records?

Comment: added as list (see update) but get:Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardController].<Constructor>(List<cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c>).Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setSelected(List<cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c>) from the type ApexPages.StandardController

Comment: It's not standardController, it's StandardSETController

Comment: oops missed that one Thanks!.

Comment: glad it worked!